# Python Plugins for QGIS

Tags: python, plugins, pyqt4

I am working with python plugins for QGIS . I am done with my one of my `.py` file using python 2.5 and pyqt4. It is just help file for QGIS, which I changed. I wanted to in-cooperate the same in QGIS. I installed QGIS 1.7.1.

I know it to be done through python plugins. But how to go about it?
where to copy my file, so that it will get open from QGIS?
QGIS already has that page(help file), I need to change it.

help me out.

Comment: This would be a better question for the QGIS mailing list, or http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're creating a QGIS plugin in Python, you may want to place it in your .qgis/python/plugins folder. Actually, you should create a subfolder below that. But that's not all, your code has to provide certain functions in order to get hooked up properly into QGIS. http://qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/plugins.html#plugins provides detailed information about that. Once your Python plugin is complete and located in the correct location, you'll have to enable it in the QGIS Plugin Manager (choose Plugins/Manage Plugins... from the manu). I'm not sure if your question is about creating QGIS Python Plugins or about replacing QGIS menu items via Python - could you clarify this? Are there any error messages for the things that are not working? Could you post your code (or relevant parts of it) for review (this might speed up the process of finding a solution)?